# How to train NER to recognize that a word is not an entity?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I may have worded my question poorly, but basically I have been training new models using spaCy for NER.  I have trained some custom entities and it's doing a really great job when I test it.  However, when I send it something that shouldn't be recognized as an entity, it seems to guess one of the entities anyways.  I am guessing it's because I never trained it what would = O(I think that's how stanford does it).

Here is a sample of my training data, does this look right?  Do I need to just add trash values and set the entity as O?

```
[ "644663" , {"entities": [[0,6, "CARDINAL"]]}],
[ "871448" , {"entities": [[0,6, "CARDINAL"]]}],
[ "6/26/1967" , {"entities": [[0,9, "DATE"]]}],
[ "1/21/1969" , {"entities": [[0,9, "DATE"]]}],
[ "GORDON GARDIN" , {"entities": [[0,13, "PERSON"]]}],
[ "CANDRA CARDINAL" , {"entities": [[0,15, "PERSON"]]}],
[ "FIAT" , {"entities": [[0,4, "CARMAKE"]]}],
[ "FORD" , {"entities": [[0,4, "CARMAKE"]]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that the problem is that you haven't shown the system anything that's *not* an entity. You don't want to add "trash values" however. Spacy expects your training strings to be strings with entities in context, not just singular examples of entities. So one training example should look more like:

`[ "My uncle drives a Ford" , {"entities": [(18,22, "CARMAKE")]}]`

This will allow your system to train to recognize entities in context, and recognize more entities than just the specific training examples you give it (e.g. a well trained system would be able to recognize "Chrysler" and "Toyota" as car makes in addition to Ford and Fiat). Spacy has more in-depth [examples](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type) for training custom entities, so I'd recommend you check that out.

Comment: Cool, thank you for that information.  So, for the portion of that string that says "My uncle drives a ".  How important is the quality of that phrase?  What if there were some bad values in that portion of the phrase?  I guess, I'm trying to understand how spaCy or machine learning in general uses that portion of the phrase to learn what items are not entities.  Would it be wise to surround the entity using words from a collection that I most likely anticipate showing up in my process?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's one single good measure of "quality" of training data. Variety of examples is important as well as making sure your training data is similar (but not too similar) to your test data. E.g. don't expect a system trained on poems to be able to extract entities from a technical manual. For how the model works it's not so much learning what isn't an entity as it is learning patterns in a sequence of words that might indicate that one of them is an entity. Here's a more in depth explanation by one of spacy's devs: https://spacy.io/api/#nn-model

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think I have a good understanding now.